# User control as Image button

Tags: asp.net

I have created user control with label and image 
i need raise event when click on the user control 
when click on the div which contain the label and image 
user control code is bellow

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ImageButton.ascx.cs" Inherits="AdvancedGrid.UC.ImageButton" %>
<div id="divClickableDiv" runat="server">
<div>
<asp:Image ID="Button_Image" ImageUrl="" runat="server" />
</div>
<div>
    <asp:Label ID="Button_Text" runat="server" Text="Button"></asp:Label>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where do you want to raise the event ? Client ? Server ?

Answer (score 0):

why not use use `ImageButton` control instead of Image if that is what you need? Try something like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ImageButton.ascx.cs" Inherits="AdvancedGrid.UC.ImageButton" %>
<div id="divClickableDiv" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="Button_Image" ImageUrl="" runat="server" OnClick="Button_Image_Click" />
</div>
<div>
    <asp:Label ID="Button_Text" runat="server" Text="Button"></asp:Label>
</div>
</div>
```

- `OnClick="Button_Image_Click"` takes you to code behind where you can go to any URL you want like this:

```
protected void Button_Image_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Response.Redirect("~/page.aspx");
}
```

- or instead of `OnClick` and without code-behind try:

```js
<asp:ImageButton ID="Button_Image" ImageUrl="" runat="server" OnClick="window.location.href = '<%= ResolveUrl("~/page.aspx") %>'" />
```

or

```js
<asp:ImageButton ID="Button_Image" ImageUrl="" runat="server" OnClientClick="window.location.href='page.aspx'; return false;" />
```